# Concatenating rows based on id name

Tags: r, dplyr, paste, tidyr

I have a dataset and I would like to concatenate the rows by specific id

```
 id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
 location<- c("Mumbai", "Newyork", "Jaipur", "Paris", "London", "Kentucky", "Dublin") 
df <- data.frame(id, location)

id   location 
1    Mumbai
1    Newyork
1    Jaipur
2    Paris
2    London
2    Kentucky
2    Dublin

 paste(location, collapse="")
```

I would like to create a column called path for each id which concatenates the rows based on id to get "Mumbai-Newyork-Jaipur"  and "Paris-London-Kentucky-Dublin". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
location<- c("Mumbai", "Newyork", "Jaipur", "Paris", "London", "Kentucky", "Dublin") 
df <- data.frame(id, location)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(path = paste(location, collapse = "-"))
```